# fping list of hosts return wrong values

Tags: linux, shell, ping

I'm trying to ping a list of hosts in parallels using fping.

```
fping -f hosts.txt
```

However it returns a lot of hosts unreachables whereas they are pingables. so it's a wrong result.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I don't believe you are missing anything. Perhaps the ip or domain name is mistyped in the file? Do you get different results when you `fping < hosts.txt`? If so, perhaps it's a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I allow myself to answer my own question because I found the solution

```
fping -i 300 -r 5 -f hosts.txt
```

so I added parameters :

- -i n --> interval between sending ping packets (in millisec) (default 25)
- -r n       number of retries (default 3)